# Correct way of referring to words in a snippet to explain words?

Tags: meaning

I have just created [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/is-it-possible-to-create-a-sourceuri-column-in-sql). I would like to know what is the correct way of referring to words in a code block in order to explain them:

> SourceURI like this:
>
> ```
> prefix:UUID:UUID
> ```
>
> In which a `prefix` is a `String`, e.g. `"hello"` and a `UUID` is a
>   `UUID`, e.g. `cd15b4ef-f3c4-49bd-92f4-10a93c041c75`.

I my opinion `in which` is not the correct way of referring. If true, what is the correct way of referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use 'where' or more formally, 'wherein'.
Another option could be 'representing' or 'represents', eg.

A URL like 'http://xyz.com' represents http as the protocol and xyz as the website name.

Similarly,

SourceURI like this:

prefix:UUID:UUID

*where* prefix is a String, e.g. "hello" and a UUID is a  UUID, e.g. cd15b4ef-f3c4-49bd-92f4-10a93c041c75.